# What is the pattern/logic behind in generating UID for Messages when using POP3 server?

Tags: java, message, jakarta-mail, pop3, uid

This question is out of curiosity, JavaMail API provides POP3 protocol provider to access POP3 messages. There is a method [POP3Folder.getUID(message)](http://javamail.kenai.com/nonav/javadocs/com/sun/mail/pop3/POP3Folder.html#getUID%28javax.mail.Message%29) available that return unique ID string for a message.  It returns, for example, in the following format:

Example UID: `1322488254.15180.1.dummy1,S=703`

My questions are:

1. Is there any logic/pattern/algorithm behind in generating this `UID` uniquely for each messages?
2. Are there any probabilities/chances of having the same UID for multiple messages?  In other words, is this truly unique?
3. Is this UID is generated by POP3 provider (JavaMail API) or returned by POP3 server?

JavaMail API doc says:

`Return the unique ID string for this message, or null if not available. Uses the POP3 UIDL command.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generated by the POP3 server.  Every server does it differently.
How perfectly it does it depends on the server, but generally I wouldn't
worry about getting the same UID for two different messages.
Depending on anything about the content or structure of the UID would be a mistake.
In particular, don't assume that they're sorted.

Comment: Regarding `Depending on anything about the content or structure of the UID would be a mistake`, but in order to determine which messages in a POP3 mailbox are "new", JavaMail API doc has suggested an approach among 3, that `to keep track of the UIDs (see below) of all messages that have been seen`.  How does it then work in that case?

Comment: You can safely compare two UIDs, for example using String.equals(). But do not try to parse them.

Comment: @HontváriJózsefLevente: My question is not about trying to parse UID, but what would happen if same UID matches 2 different messages, if I were keeping track of UID of messages that have been seen?

Comment: As Bill Shannon wrote, you should not worry about finding the same UID. If a POP server returns the same UID for two different messages in normal circumstances, then that is a bug in the POP server. For example in my POP3 store I use a 8 byte long integer counter to assign UIDs, incrementing after each mail. That should be enough for everybody. I can imagine only one case when a client gets the same UID: if the user mailbox is deleted and then recreated with the same name, the UID sequence will restart. If that becomes a realistic scenario, then I will have to change my implementation.